# Setting timeout for all the ProxyPass mappings in Apache Server mod_proxy directive

Tags: apache, apache2, mod-proxy, apache2.2

**What I have and works:**

I'm using *Apache HTTPD 2.2* for proxy requests. I have multiple *ProxyPass* mappings:

```
ProxyRequests On 
<Proxy *>
AddDefaultCharset off
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
</Proxy>
ProxyPreserveHost Off

ProxyPass /a http://some_ip/
ProxyPassReverse /a http://some_ip/

ProxyPass /b http://some_other_ip/
ProxyPassReverse /b http://some_other_ip/

...
```

This works well.

**What I want:**

Some of my requests are taking longer, so they timed out giving me a ***Proxy Error - Reason: Error reading from remote server***.

I want to set `timeout` for all of my requests. Can I do this without having to add `timeout=... KeepAlive=On` for every `ProxyPass` mapping?

I currently have something like:

```
ProxyPass /a http://some_ip/ timeout=1200 KeepAlive=On
ProxyPassReverse /a http://some_ip/

ProxyPass /b http://some_other_ip/ timeout=1200 KeepAlive=On
ProxyPassReverse /b http://some_other_ip/

... and i do this for all my ProxyPass mappings
```

Can I tell Apache in some way to add `timeout` and `KeepAlive` parameters for all the mappings? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Off topic. Try serverfault.com.

Comment: I agree with you that it goes better in ServerFault, but there are Apache and mod_proxy related tags, are there not? My question targets the mod_proxy directive settings of Apache 2.2 Server.

Comment: I know, thank you for that. I managed however to find a solution by my own and I'm adding it here, maybe someone finds it useful.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I've managed to find a solution by my own. You can set the timeout using directly the `ProxyTimeout` directive of `mod_proxy` :

```
ProxyRequests On 
<Proxy *>
    AddDefaultCharset off
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
</Proxy>
ProxyPreserveHost Off

ProxyTimeout 1200
```

Comment: What is that ProxyPreserveHost for ? To setting timeout ProxyTimeout Directive isn't enough !!!! Do we have to specify all these lines to setup ProxyTimeout ?

Comment: Where are these lines added?

Comment: The directive `ProxyTimeout` can be placed in: **server config** and under **virtual host**. Initial question was about all of the requests made, which means global scope (server config), thus I would put it to `/etc/apache2/mods-available/proxy.conf` or familiar file under Apache conf dir, to keep it in order. However, in practice, it can be placed anywhere. I would also wrapped it in `<IfModule mod_proxy.c></IfModule>` to avoid a failure upon migration or module package removable.